# DriverPackagePreinstall error with dpinst.exe

Tags: winapi, driver, inf, dpinst

When trying to install a driver using *Microsoft Driver Package Installer DPInst* I got error **0xE0000247**.
I tried to check the error code with *Visual Studio Lookup Tool* but the tool doesn't know this error code. Also MSDN doesn't help here.

**How can I lookup the meaning of this error ?**

Below a fragment of my *DPINST.LOG* file:

> ```
> INFO:   Install option set: Running in quiet mode. Suppressing Wizard and OS popups.
> INFO:   Install option set: legacy mode on.
> INFO:   Install option set: Suppressing EULA.
> INFO:   Install option set: Force install if driver is not better.
> INFO:   Install option set: Suppress Add or Remove Programs entries.
> INFO:   Found driver package: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\my_driver.inf'.
> INFO:   Preinstalling 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\my_driver.inf' ...
> INFO:   ENTER:  DriverPackagePreinstallW
> INFO:   RETURN: DriverPackagePreinstallW  (0xE0000247)
> INFO:   Returning with code 0x80010000
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from `SetupAPI.h` (irrelevant lines omitted):

```
#define APPLICATION_ERROR_MASK       0x20000000
#define ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR         0xC0000000
#define ERROR_DRIVER_STORE_ADD_FAILED (APPLICATION_ERROR_MASK|ERROR_SEVERITY_ERROR|0x247)
```

So your error is `ERROR_DRIVER_STORE_ADD_FAILED` which is a generic error code returned by `SetupCopyOEMInf` which in turn is called by `DriverPackagePreinstall` internally.

The cause of this error is poorly documented but doesn't seem to be related to any specific type of error (hence I called it "generic"). The name itself suggests that the driver could not be added to the [driver store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544868(v=vs.85).aspx) (or the [DIFx driver store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543652(v=vs.85).aspx) for OS versions prior to Windows Vista) which could have various reasons (insufficient access rights, validation of the driver package failed, ...).

From personal experience I can tell you that most of the time when this error occurs there is a problem with the certificate used to sign the driver package on 64-bit Windows. (Which should really be one of the `CERT_E_*` error codes, but well...)