# Driver install error on Windows 11 Home Insider Preview x86_64

Tags: windows-installer, driver, code-signing, inf, windows-11

A user reported an install problem. I asked them to start setup from the command line with the verbose logging option, and this seems to be where the problem is:

```
DIFXAPP: INFO:   ENTER:  DriverPackageInstallW
DIFXAPP: INFO:   RETURN: DriverPackageInstallW  (0xE0000247)
DIFXAPP: ERROR: encountered while installing driver package 'C:\Program Files\AcmeWidgets\WidgetApp\widget-driver.inf'
DIFXAPP: ERROR: InstallDriverPackages failed with error 0xE0000247
DIFXAPP: RETURN: InstallDriverPackages() 3758096967 (0xE0000247)
CustomAction MsiInstallDrivers returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 21:00:47: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (50:CC) [...]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035
```

Our driver is signed (Digicert EV Code Signing Certificate), and our Windows 10 and other Windows 11 users are able to install the app with no apparent issues.

Could this be a known issue with Windows 11 Insider Preview?

Comment: Had the same problem. Took a look at %windir%\INF\Setupapi.dev.log and found further information there including ``Error 0x800b010c: A certificate was explicitly revoked by its issuer.`` 
Am still struggling to find the reason for that, though.

Comment: Stumbled upon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/563417/usbserinf-windows-update-error-0x8007054f-during-i.html which is quite recent and also implies some INF installation problem. Maybe there's a relationship or common cause?

Comment: [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28862880/129130).  [Did you try this suggestion](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/hqgj24/false_certificate_was_explicitly_revoked_by_its/)? Maybe the certificate got corrupted at some point?

Comment: @FlorianStraub - I've escalated this with Microsoft Insider Program reps. I don't know if our problems are identical, but I'll update you when I hear back from them.

Comment: @FlorianStraub - I've gotten no response at all from anyone at Microsoft, despite posting multiple times/places, and explicitly asking for their attention. I've been trying to create a PAID support ticket for two weeks now, but it keeps expiring/getting canceled, and no one contacts me... Why is it always like this with Microsoft?

Comment: I saw that one of our drivers is signed with an SHA1 hash still, maybe that's the problem. I didn't have a customer with the problem since I've found out, though.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft [announced deprecating DIfX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/difx-guidelines) in Windows 10. Maybe they don't support it at all in Windows 11? Is this package working fine on Windows 10 machines?

Also, have you tried multiple Win11 machines?

Comment: I have the same problem with a customer. Therefore I tested the installer on some other Windows 11 machine and it worked like a charm. So I guess difx generally works at Windows 11.

Comment: Yeah, this only seems to affect Win 11 Insider Preview users, and only some of them. The error seems to be about an intermediate cert in the chain of trust. But I can't reproduce this in captivity, and the verbose install logs I get from affected users don't specifically identify the cert.